# C programming for sinusoidal wave generation

Tags: c, math, simulation, waveform, trigonometry

I have written a code that is used as a User defined function in ANSYS fluent simulation. This code is intended to produce a sinusoidal deformation  on a channel wall. according to the following equation

```
H(x) = a + b*Sin (2π/λ) (x - ct)
```

Where

```
‘a’ is the average height of the channel 
‘b’ is the amplitude of the wave 
‘c’ is the wave propagation speed 
‘λ’ is the wavelength 
‘x’ is the stream wise direction of the flow ‘
t’ is current time
```

the problem I am facing is that " how can I write the code in order to move each node on 2D channel wall according to the above given equation"

```
#include "udf.h"
#include "dynamesh_tools.h"
DEFINE_GRID_MOTION(peristaltic, domain, dt, time, dtime)
{

    Thread *tf= DT_THREAD(dt);
    face_t f;
    Node *v;
    real NV_VEC(omega), NV_VEC(axis), NV_VEC(dx);
    real NV_VEC(origin), NV_VEC(rvec);
    real sign;
int n;
SET_DEFORMING_THREAD_FLAG(THREAD_T0(tf));
sign = 0.5 + 2*sin(6.28 * time);
Message ("time = %f, omega = %f\n", time, sign);
NV_S(omega, =, 0.0);
NV_D(axis, =, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
NV_D(origin, =, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

begin_f_loop(f,tf)
 {
f_node_loop(f,tf,n)
{   

v = F_NODE(f,tf,n);
if (NODE_POS_NEED_UPDATE (v))
{
/* indicate that node position has been update */
/*so that it's not updated more than once */
    NODE_POS_UPDATED(v);
NV_VV(rvec, =, NODE_COORD(v), -, origin);
NV_CROSS(dx, omega, rvec);
NV_S(dx, *=, dtime);
NV_V(NODE_COORD(v), +=, dx);
    }
     }
}   
end_f_loop(f,tf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
H(x) = a + b*Sin (2π/λ * x - wt)
```

or

```
H(x) = a + b*Sin ((2π/λ) * (x - ct))
```

for each channel - you need to loop around all your x values for all of your times.

something like

```
for (n=0,x=min;n<100;n++;x+=(max-min)/99) 
{
  sign[n] = 0.5 + 2*sin(2*M_PI/lambda *(x - 6.28 * time));
}
```

where sign is now an array and you calculate the disturbance for many channels at different values of x,  hope this helps

(NB for wave to move in +ve x direction need -ct , which is at first counter intuitive)